# Two column bootstrap layout without any padding or spaces

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is similar to the layout I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The code I have now

```
 <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-lg-6 row-eq-height push-right">
            <img src="1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 row-eq-height">
            <div class="eq-row-text ">
                 <p class="row-text">Text description for image </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row ">
         <div class="col-lg-6 row-eq-height ">
            <div class="eq-row-text ">
                 <p class="row-text"> Text description for the image </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 row-eq-height">
            <img src="1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried using CSS class "no-padding" and also tried playing around with margins. when i apply 0 padding, the left side of the first image touches the edge of the browser( this is desired), however the other edge(right side of image) still has some empty space.

How do I get rid of that empty space get the results like the reference layout?

Comment: You probably need a larger image to fill the empty space on the right side. Also, removing padding from `col-**-**` elements will make your columns' content pull outside of the `.row` elements as they have negative left and right margins equal to the padding on the column elements.

Answer (score 0):

There could be an issue with the `<p>` padding/margin, could also be an issue with the `<img>` padding/margin. However it seems to be an issue with the sizing of the elements within the row.

I did however seemingly fix the issue in my [PEN HERE](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/EggLEx)

I added a `height: ***` to the row class, this may be needed for desired results as you are using `row-eq-height` bootstrap class.

HTML

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-lg-6  row-eq-height push-right">
        <img src="1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 row-eq-height">
        <div class="eq-row-text ">
            <p class="row-text">Text description for image </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6 row-eq-height ">
          <div class="eq-row-text ">
               <p class="row-text"> Text description for the image </p>
          </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 row-eq-height">
          <img src="1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.row {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:60px;
    background-color: #eee
}
```

Comment: Don't see the reason for the downvote, See the pen, issue resolved.

Comment: Globally resetting element styles and Bootstrap classes to target specific container elements seems like a bad idea. There's likely a lot of elements that don't want/need the global reset. Perhaps scope the styles to the target containers.

Comment: Yes I understand that he may not need to reset global variables, they were included to show they do, in fact, nothing for his issue. This is not a moment to teach ideal standards but rather focus on the question at hand. Bootstrap 4 also has [utility classes](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/) to assist with margin/padding via the framework.

Comment: I'm going to disagree. You have specific markup so giving an example of scoped CSS is trivial. For example, instead of `p {}` you could give an example of along the lines of `.has-featured-img p {}` and then apply that class to `.row`. Not hard to do.

Comment: Right on, I'll do better. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
.col-md-6{
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the LESS/SASS source: change `@grid-gutter-width` in the variables file to 0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the white space you will need to make your image bigger to span the cols. You can manually adjust the width of an image using css:

```
img {
     width: 100%; 
}
```